# Determining the structure of an 'MCA' object in R and calculating 2d coordinate distances

Tags: r

I have an MCA object generated from function MCA in package missMDA, which returns several types of results from Multiple Correspondence Analysis.  Of these, I want to be able to use the 'dist' function, if appropriate, to calculate all pairwise 2d distances among the coordinates.  Before I can do that, it seems that I need to figure out how to specifically reference the vectors of X and Y coordinates from this object, but when I ask for mydata$var$coord I get an unruly list of values, and I'm not sure how to send the results to an appropriate format that the dist function can use.

I am also  interested in learning how to understand the structure of different kinds of objects in general, so that I have will a clearer roadmap for referencing their components in the future (and don't have to come groveling back to all of you seeking help with that!).

My apologies if I haven't stated my question clearly enough.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what to do, which is (apparently) R 101:

```
names(mydata)
```

Gave me the appropriate information about the components of this object (a list of type MCA).  From this, I was able to reference the component of interest -

```
mydata$ind$coord

mydata$var$coord
```

I guess it pays to be patient!